# On click of save button, onsubmit function is not called

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have used the lightning:recordEditForm. On click of the save button, the onsubmit function is not called.

If the submit function is called on the button onclick, then the record gets saved, but the onsuccess function is not called.

Component:

```
    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" 
        recordId="!v.selectedConfigId}" 
        objectApiName="Priority_Points_Settings__c"
        onsubmit="{!c.onEditRecordSubmit}"
        onsuccess="{!c.onRecordSuccess}">
        <lightning:messages />

        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
            <!-- lightning:inputField components here -->
        </div>                              
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" type="submit"/>
```

Controller:

```
onEditRecordSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
        component.find('recordEditForm').submit();
    },


onRecordSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('>>In success');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is because of the `lightning:button` being outside of `lightning:recordEditForm`.

You will need to place the button within the form  so that the button is wired with the form and its handler functions `onsubmit` and `onsuccess`.

Your component should look like this:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" 
    recordId="!v.selectedConfigId}" 
    objectApiName="Priority_Points_Settings__c"
    onsubmit="{!c.onEditRecordSubmit}"
    onsuccess="{!c.onRecordSuccess}">
    <lightning:messages />

    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <!-- lightning:inputField components here -->
    </div>                              

    <!-- button has been moved within the form -->
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" type="submit"/>    
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Comment: Tried above changes.. But still facing same problem.

Comment: You may like to refresh the cache. I was able to reproduce the issue and fix it with the approach as mentioned. The button always needs to be within the form for this to work.

Comment: @Ajinkyasd Apart from the answer, [`event.preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on your function `onEditRecordSubmit()` is blocking the action.

Comment: @Raul even with `event.preventDefault()`, the button being within the form works fine. I was able to get it working only when button was moved within the form.

Comment: oh, when I added prevent default to my existing working component, submit handler was not saving the record. so thought that maybe the second problem.

Comment: @Raul always good to know something new. I went back to see if I had this piece in the code I was trying to replicate with, and found it was working fine.

Comment: It works, controller and helper function gets called as usual, but with `event.preventDefault()`  the changes are to fields are not saved to database. Giving a perception that controller method is not getting called.

Comment: If the <lightning:outputField is used in the <lightning:recordEditForm then the form is not saved and the following exception: "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: 1839189030)". Works fine for <lightning:inputField.

Comment: That could be an unrelated issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure by this time you have found the solution for your issue or not. but for future reference'rs if any, might find helpful hence providing the solution.

In Your code the fields variable is missing . You are directly calling the form with form id but not providing the form fields values for submit function.

Try This:

```
onEditRecordSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
event.preventDefault();
var fields = event.getParam("fields");
component.find('recordEditForm').submit(fields);
    }
```